# Conditionals with int and string

Tags: java, string, int, conditional-statements

I'm making a payroll program and one of the options is to check data on current users.  I want to allow the user to enter either the employee's ID or name to retrieve this information.

```
Scanner userChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter employee ID or full name");
String checkHEmp = userChoice.next();
int checkHempID = userChoice.nextInt(); 
    if (checkHempID ==3|| checkHEmp == "Jill Jones") {
        HourlyEmployee jones = new HourlyEmployee();
        jones.jJones();
    }
```

In this example HourlyEmployee is a class of hourly employees and jJones() is a method in that class that contains the information for one of the employees.  When I enter either "3" (the ID) or "Jill Jones" nothing happens afterwards.

Edit: Added method for jJones()

```
public void jJones() {
    double hourlyWagesJones = 16.45;
    double hoursWorkedJones = 48;

    System.out.println("Employee ID: 3");
    System.out.println("Last name: Jones");
    System.out.println("First name: Jill");
    System.out.println("Date Hired: 1/22/2011");
    System.out.println("Hours Worked: " + hoursWorkedJones);
    System.out.println("Hourly Wages: $" + hourlyWagesJones);
    double totalEarnedJones = new Double(hourlyWagesJones * hoursWorkedJones);
    System.out.println("Total earned: $" + totalEarnedJones);   
}
```

Comment: Entering the number 3 should work so if that actually is a problem then you should clarify your question by stating your input, output, the contents of the `jJones` method and giving us a reproduceable example.

Comment: in addition, print `checkHEmp` and see what you get

Comment: If you input 3 it goes into the `checkHEmp` variable which you are checking if it is `"Jill Jones"`.

Comment: I changed the string conditional to .equals instead but I am still getting the same problem. I'm getting [this](http://imgur.com/6KJsDXe) in Debug.

Comment: Let me guess: you're entering "Jill Jones" first and "3" second?

Comment: When I print out checkHEmp, only the first name gets printed before the program crashes and enters Debug
Scanner is imported. 
Even when I only enter "3" nothing happens. I have the code written to print both checkHEmp (string) and checkHempID (int) but neither prints

Comment: I would add that `checkHEmp` is a pretty bad variable name - pretty easy to glance at it the wrong way and think it's `checkEmp`. Why not `checkHourlyEmployee`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so,

```
String checkHEmp = userChoice.next();
```

is a expecting a `String` and the `String` you enter is "Jill Jones", but `Scanner`'s default delimiter is `" "` which means that it will read up to the first `" "` it finds, so only the `Jill` will be stored in `checkHEmp` which of course is not what you check for in your `if` statement.

In the case that you only pass the number `3`, or pass it before the `String` you will get an error again because `Scanner` will first look for a `String` and will find an `int` instead.

What you can do is replace:

```
String checkHEmp = userChoice.next();
```

with

```
String checkHEmp = userChoice.nextLine();
```

and either remove

```
int checkHempID = userChoice.nextInt();`
```

or if you want to keep it you have to enter the name **first** , press Enter to go to a new line, enter the number and press enter again.

You also need to change

```
if (checkHempID == 3 || checkHEmp == "JillJones")
```

to

```
if (checkHempID == 3 || checkHEmp.equals("JillJones"));
```

Another thing you can do is :

```
Scanner userChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter employee ID or full name");
String checkHEmp = "";
int checkHempID = 0;
if(userChoice.hasNextInt())
    checkHempID = userChoice.nextInt();
else 
    checkHEmp += userChoice.nextLine();
if (checkHempID == 3|| checkHEmp.equals("Jill Jones")) {
    //do whatever
}
```

This way you need to **EITHER** enter `3` or `"Jill Jones"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code is exactly what I needed.  So is userChoice.hasNextInt() supposed to test if what the user enters is an integer?

Comment: It will store the next `int` it finds to the variable you assign it. If it finds a `String` instead you are in trouble. If you don't know know what comes next then you need some logic to handle it. Something like what i did on the last part